# How to remove the router from the Quasar bootstrap project?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am trying to trim down the bootstrap project in Quasar v2, to a single .vue file (mostly to understand how this project works).

I managed to just have the `App.vue` as

```
<template>
  <div>
    hello
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App'
})
</script>
```

All the other layouts components are removed, mostly thanks to having `routes.ts` almost empty:

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue'),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

**My question: how can I completely remove the router from the bootstrap example?** Where does Quasar configures its usage (= the fact that a router is used in the first place).